# Adding button to stack view entirely takes up of parent stack view

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift5

I have been trying to add buttons to a dynamic vertical stack view, the stack view is in a scroll view that's in a horizontal stack view. Whenever I add a button to the stack view it takes up the entire horizontal stack view, here it is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        Stack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        Stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    }
```

Entire code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emotionsStack: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("test", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: emotionsStack.frame.width, height: (emotionsStack.frame.width/10))
        emotionsStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
    }
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches,
                           with: event)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
    }
```

EDIT:
[image: explanation]

What happens is that the stackview takes over the textview (that is in red). This isn't supposed to happen.

[image]

Comment: You're going to need to share more information about the content in each stack view and scroll view. There isn't enough information here to help you.

Comment: Well, you're never going to get that first picture, because what would make the stack view put the button _near_ the left side but not _at_ the left side? I would suggest that this layout would be a lot easier to create if you just threw the stack view away and lay it out yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as stackView didn't detect the size so you have to give each button a fixed size width or height depends on the type of stackView "Vertical or Horizontal" so try to give your button a width and it will work.

-> you can use stackView width or height and minus the spaces then divide it by number of buttons and then assign the value for each button

Edited:
After editing my answer I have added a block of code and an image if you need like this, if not, provide an image which shows which result do you want:

```
import UIKit

class StackViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var textView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var emotionsStack: UIStackView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        for i in 0...10 {
        let button = UIButton()
        button.setTitle("test \(i)", for: .normal)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true
        button.frame.size = CGSize(width: emotionsStack.frame.width, height: ((emotionsStack.frame.width - 30 )/10))
        emotionsStack.addArrangedSubview(button)
        }
    }
    
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches,
                           with: event)
        self.view.endEditing(true)
    }
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: Try to set button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = true. And give horizontal centre constraint to stack view if you want to set button left side then set trailing constraint >=

Comment: I already did it by give the stackView itself constrains to meet the requirements he needs